# Delete query using WHERE EXISTS matches more rows than the subquery returns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am not able to figure out what is going on with my delete statement, it wants to delete many more rows than the select statement returns.

If I run the following in an MS Access query I get 168 rows:

```
Select dbo_member.memberid from claims JOIN dbo_member on (claims.idnum = dbo_member.idnum);
```

dbo_member is a SQL table and is linked in MS Access.  Claims is a table only in MS Access.

When I run this, MS Access wants to delete 130K rows:

```
Delete from claims where exists (Select dbo_member.memberid from claims JOIN dbo_member on (claims.idnum = dbo_member.idnum);)
```

When I was doing some other delete statements earlier, they worked but I don't remember those having joins in them.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has multiple problems:

When I try to execute the following query in Access

```sql
Select dbo_member.memberid 
from 
    claims 
    JOIN 
    dbo_member 
        on (claims.idnum = dbo_member.idnum);
```

I get "Syntax error in FROM clause". Access SQL does not support an unqualified `JOIN` specifier. However,

```sql
Select dbo_member.memberid 
from 
    claims 
    INNER JOIN 
    dbo_member 
        on (claims.idnum = dbo_member.idnum);
```

works and returns 168 rows. Now, applying the same correction to your second query (and ignoring the spurious semi-colon for now),

```sql
Delete from claims 
where exists 
    (
        Select dbo_member.memberid 
        from 
            claims 
            INNER JOIN 
            dbo_member 
                on (claims.idnum = dbo_member.idnum);
    )
```

says that it wants to delete **every row in the [claims] table**. Why? It's because you haven't included a WHERE clause in the subquery relating it to the outer query. Therefore, when the database engine asks "Does a row exist in the subquery for the current row in the outer query?" the answer is always "Yes".

What I *think* you really want is

```sql
DELETE FROM claims
WHERE 
    idnum IN
        (
            SELECT idnum FROM dbo_member
        )
```